# Is there anyway to access variables from one class in another?

Tags: c#, class

So I got 2 classes, Movie and Customer, Movie contains Variables such as the number of tickets bought and the number of tickets reserved. How can the Customer class access these variables without creating the movie objects inside the customer class and without setting them to static?
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thank you BradleyDotNET for clearing up my utmost stupidity. I wasn't even aware you could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass them in as parameters, or set them to properties. Just like any other variable. For example

**Main**

```
Movie superAwesomeActionFlick = new Movie();
Customer moviegoer = new Customer();
customer.WatchMovie(superAwesomeActionFlick);
```

**Customer**

```
public void WatchMovie(Movie movie)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{movie.Title} is great!!!");
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use a user input to decide which movie object is accessed?

Comment: @Bearowl Sure; again just like any other variable. Any movie object is a valid argument to the method. Do you understand how variables/parameters/arguments work?

Comment: I'm out of the loop for this one tbh if the User input is in string how can I use it to decide which object to access. I'm sorry for my incompetence

Comment: @Bearowl There really isn't enough info in your comment to determine how to answer that; I would suggest incorporating the answer I just gave into your code, grinding on it for a bit, and if you still have trouble post a *new* question with the updated code and your problem